# Can trial-level reaction-times be used to predict subject-level scores of another task?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, psychology

I would like to predict whether single Reaction-Times (RTs) in a computer task can predict subject performance on a comprehension task. For each subject, I have many RTs but only 1 comprehension score.

Example data structure (my_data):

| Subject_ID | Trial | RT | Comperhension_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 1 | 250 | 20 |
| P001 | 2 | 260 | 20 |
| P001 | 3 | 245 | 20 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| P005 | 1 | 255 | 31 |
| P005 | 2 | 270 | 31 |
| P005 | 3 | 280 | 31 |

I'm using `nlme`, my model is `my_model <- lme(Comprehension_Score ~ RT, random = (~1|Subject_ID), data = my_data)`

I want to analyse at the trial-level because my understanding is that this preserves information and can improve statistical power, but is it valid to repeat Comprehension_score participant-wise and run this model? Or should you always reduce the data so that all the measures are on the same scale.

Edit: Alternatively, is there a way to modify the model (e.g., adjusting random effects) to make it valid?

Thank you!

Comment: How many trials did each participant complete? And how many participants do you have?

Comment: @awhug There are ~45 reaction times per participant, and there are ~30 participants. Although I am attempting to trial-level analyses to improve power, my question is more about the validity of repeating participant-level scores in a trial-level analyses.

Comment: Interesting question! My non-expert intuition is that your model formulation is not correct. Allowing Comprehension_score to differ between participants with a random intercept would absorb all of the outcome variance (as 100% of the variation is between participants). If it makes sense in your experiment, could you swap the predictor and outcome in the model? This would be a more classic mixed model. Hope someone more knowledgeable can help!

Comment: @Lachlan Thank you for your input! Your non-expert intuition makes sense to me. I hadn't considered that the random effect might absorb the variance of Comprehension_score. Since there is only a single predictor, I think I can swap the IV and DV. 

Regarding my OP, I think I will compute subject-wise mean RTs and run a linear model for now.